# Muted video tag if removed won't play

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, tags

I have this code of HTML I got from w3schools.
But , the video tag is kinda odd.
I would like to have the video unmuted so then I removed the
muted tag but when it was removed , it doesn't even
playing just a black screen.

I tried searching all the codes of the word "muted" and "silent"
Nothing is working. Not found. Bam.

Someone help me please.

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I have no clear idea why If I remove that muted tag. They won't play the video.
anyway full code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#myBtn {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi pro.</p>
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
</div>

<script>
   document.addEventListener('click', musicPlay);
function musicPlay() {
    document.getElementById('ID').play();
    document.removeEventListener('click', musicPlay);
}
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the issue, but you can try this fix using [`onloadeddata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onloadeddata) :

```
<video id="myVideo" onloadeddata="this.play();" loop>
  <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

DEMO:

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" onloadeddata="this.play();" loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<br/><br/>
<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
```

Comment: hey bud thanks. but. can you make the autoplay working. i tried puttig the autoplay tag but it deosnt work (sorry broken keyboarD)

Answer (score 1):

For videos to autoplay on the web, you must include the muted attribute.

This has been true in Chrome and Safari for a few years now:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

If you want to be able to start/stop the movie, you might consider adding the controls attribute:

```html
<video autoplay muted loop controls id="myVideo">
  <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just `play/pause` the video. its not actual mute controls.use [`video.muted`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_muted.asp) dom api

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
    btn.innerHTML = video.muted ? "Unmute":'Mute';
    video.muted = !video.muted;
}
```

```css
#myBtn {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi
    pro.
  </p>
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Unmute</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's your complete edited code as your answer.

my changes: `<video controls autoplay id="myVideo">`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        #myVideo {
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        .content {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: #f1f1f1;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        #myBtn {
            width: 200px;
            font-size: 18px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: none;
            background: #000;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #myBtn:hover {
            background: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <video controls autoplay id="myVideo">
        <source src="rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>

    <div class="content">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis
            neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine
            molestiae, ad mutat oblique delicatissimi pro.</p>
        <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('click', musicPlay);
        function musicPlay() {
            document.getElementById('ID').play();
            document.removeEventListener('click', musicPlay);
        }
        var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        function myFunction() {
            if (video.paused) {
                video.play();
                btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
            }
            else {
                video.pause();
                btn.innerHTML = "Play";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```